# Information on accessing SVN repositories via PHP

Tags: php, svn

Googling this does little good, as you can imagine.

Does anyone have resources that outline how the PHP Subversion support works. I need to open a repository on disk, and read new commit logs, etc.

Anything you have, would be helpful. Except the PHP docs. I have those already :)

Comment: Were you running into problems with the documentation, or just looking for some examples?  I haven't used this extension before but it seems relatively straightforward if you're accustomed to using Subversion from the command line.

Comment: Primarily looking for examples. I have learned that php wrappers for command line tools can quite a few hidden gotchas. :) Therefore was hoping to read some information from those more experienced with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I need to access a SVN repository from PHP, I often end up using the "svn" command, calling it with [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [`passthru`](http://php.net/passthru) -- it's working pretty well ; only requires that there is an svn client installed on the machine, which is always the case for my computers.

A nice thing to note is that the svn command supports an --xml option, at least for some commands -- and XML is easy to parse with PHP, using, for instance, [`simplexml_load_string`](http://php.net/simplexml_load_string).

Well, at least, it's far easier than parsing the output of the svn command ^^

Another solution would be to use the [`VersionControl_SVN`](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.tools.versioncontrol-svn.php) library ; it, itself, acts as a wrapper arround the svn command, and might help you by already doing a part of the work for you.

Finally, if you can install PHP extensions on your server, there is a [PECL SVN extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/svn) -- [here is its manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php).

I've never used it, and it's marked as "beta", so your host might not like it... Still, I've heard that it works OK a couple of times.

Of course, in either case, knowing a bit about SVN, how it works, how the svn command works, and what kind of informations/output it can get, is quite helpful.

Hope this helps ; if you have more specific questions, don't hesitate :-)